# Ionic angular state routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

The state routing is not working well for me.
The first link called **home** loads automatically if I click the link in home  page it should go to **search** page but instead it appends the data to the home page itself. so I see both home and search page data in same page.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<!--<base href="/">-->
</head>
<body ng-app="hello">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
angular.module('hello', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "/home.html"

            });
  $stateProvider.state('search', {
        url: "/search",
        templateUrl: "/search.html"
            });
    });
```

home.html

```
<a href="#/search">Go to Search</a>
```

search.html

```
<div> you are in Search Screen</div>
```

I have created a Plunker , but for some reason I don't see any output http://plnkr.co/edit/UpnS01Oy2MLqHvKSAPST

Comment: Any errors in console when you click on the link?
Did you try with ui-sref attribute?
Like `ui-sref="search"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in your code:  the view must be wrapped in `<ion-view>` element.

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content>
    <a href="#/search">Go to Search</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the Plunker with corrections:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ONAIfq26uwN7ZoYQtY0N?p=preview

PS: pay attention before Ionic build add reference to cordova.js.

Comment: Thanks your Plunker works Perfect let me put this in my code